# What's the current state of RFC 822/3696 etc. (email addresses) in practical, real world use?

Tags: validation, email

[RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822), [3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696) and others specify email address formats and how those should be validated by applications. Unfortunately in practice virtually nobody adheres to them, with most developers tending to invent a regex on the fly or copy-n-paste one from dubious sources to validate their user's email addresses. This in practice leads to many web services requiring email addresses, often as the primary identity of their users, yet only accepting a very limited subset of addresses that the RFCs actually allow.

So, can anything be said about the current state of what is generally considered a "web safe" email address? Is there some common subset that has crystalized over time that's accepted by most services? What's the standard for the HTML 5 `email` input type, which will hopefully eventually emerge as the default quick front-end validity check for emails?

---

Please note that I'm not asking what *should* be done to validate email addresses. Ideally validation should consist of light front-end validation which allows every possible address and possibly some false-positives, followed by a callback validation with the actual email server on the backend. I'm asking instead whether there is any sort of consensus on what the current implementations in the wild regard as valid. If I were to create a regex to validate email addresses (which I'm not, but humor me), what should that be to roughly match what everyone else does? If I were to create a new email address for myself on  my own server, what safe subset should I stick to in order to be able to use that address at most web sites?

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your own question in your first paragraph.

TL;DR there is no consensus.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much know that. ;-) However, I was hoping for something like a study, survey, analysis of source code of commonly used libraries or something to at least be able to say "`+_-.a-z`" are typically allowed, anything else not so much... :)

Comment: Just implement a validator based on the syntax of rfc821 (not 822) and you'll be fine. If you need an example, see here (non-regex): http://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidator - it basically just checks that the syntax is correct by tokenizing the string. If it tokenizes correctly, then it's "valid" (or at least as valid as you can determine w/o actually trying to send mail to the address).

Comment: Yes, sure, that'd be my strategy as well. My question is different though. I guess it's basically unanswerable, but I wanted to give it a shot anyway. :)

Comment: The `github` link is depreciated as the repository name has changed, try this if needed: https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation